# @ActiveProfile and spring.profiles.active

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, applicationcontext, profiles

This is a piece of my applicationContext definition to retrieve some properties.

```
 <!-- get some properties -->
<context:property-placeholder
        ignore-resource-not-found="false" ignore-unresolvable="false"
        location="classpath:/properties/${spring.profiles.active:test}/some.properties"/>
```

As you can see I letting the spring.profiles.active decide which properties will be read.
My tests are annotated with:

```
@ActiveProfile("integration")
```

You guessed it right my spring bean profiles are actually matching the environments in which to deploy/test the application.
Still my location property is getting resolved to "/properties/test/some.properties". Which is of course because the spring.profiles.active doesn't seem to get resolved in this case.

How could I achieve getting the the right properties?

Answer (score 1):

It is because active profiles **may** be activated by system property (but in case of `@ActiveProfiles` it works another way).

Just like this:

```
<beans profile="dev,prod,qa">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:some.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:some-test.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>
```

Also, you may try to change
    `location="classpath:/properties/${spring.profiles.active:test}/some.properties"`
to 
    `location="classpath:/properties/${spring.profiles.active}/some.properties"`

Comment: That is indeed a workaround I was also thinking about, but still this feels like a bug to me in the @ActiveProfile annotation implementation. I would have expected it to set the spring.profiles.active property for completeness sake. I`m not a big fan of writing a lot of xml.

Comment: In such case you may add custom JUnitTestRunner and set system property according to @ActiveProfiles

Comment: We could also set the propertysource using @PropertySource and make sure our PropertyPlaceHolder does not complain about missing property files. But the point is getting lost of having this property.

Answer (score 1):

See ticket: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8982#comment-88498

Someone already had made a request for this:

> An option to override an @ActiveProfile specified by test in runtime from command line by "-Dspring.profiles.active" or other systemProperty

My comment:

> That or it should set the property spring.profiles.active.