# Run TestNG class programmatically with parameters like a specific active profile and context configuration etc

Tags: java, spring, testng

I have an integration tests class extended from AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. I want to run test class twice, each time with a different profile programmatically and not by hard-coding profile and configuration xml as below.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:MyBatisBeanConfiguration.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles("cloud")
public class MyIntegrationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
  @Test
  public void myTest()
  {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15245806/180100 might help.

Comment: Thanks @RC. Meanwhile I think I need to get into code base of spring test framework and see how it executes the testNG tests with specific profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the VM argument spring.profiles.active to enable certain spring profile(s) in your tests (or any other application for that matter).

Example: `-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud,someOtherProfile`